# How to install gtkmm?

Tags: software-installation, programming, c++, gtk3

Is the gtkmm package already installed by default? If not how do I install it on Ubuntu with all the prerequisites? Would a command line install be better? Do I need to add a repository?

Answer (score 6):

No, the packages you need are not installed by default but are available in the normal Ubuntu repositories. You can use `sudo apt install`.

Be sure to have the C++-Compiler installed:

```
g++
```

For C++ programming you need to install the development version of the important GNOME libraries. Those contain the header files and additional linker information:

```
libgtkmm-3.0-dev
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev
```

In addition, you will want to install the documentation packages of this libraries so you can view them in the API browser (devhelp):

```
libgtkmm-3.0-doc
libgstreamermm-1.0-doc
devhelp
```

-- [Source](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/DeveloperTools/Installation/Ubuntu)

I recommend you also install gnome-devel-docs to look at some demos. After installing, run

```
yelp help:gnome-devel-demos
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 11.10 comes with  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a and libgtkmm-3.0-1

libgtkmm-3.0-1 is installed by default